# Assembly al used in mov [esp], al

Tags: assembly, x86

I am very new in assembly language, and i can't understand this code.

```
mov byte [esp + 0x1], al
```

I'm not sure, but this line set the al value at esp+0x1 byte position right? In my case, al is never used with:

```
'mov al, <value>'
```

What is the value set in the first line if al doesn't have value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure, but this line set the al value at esp+0x1 byte position right?

That is correct. It's like `[esp + 1] = al`

`al` is a register and a register always has a value. Probably you haven't set it, but maybe an other function used it before.

Comment: Thank you for the precision!  If i haven't set it, its value is 0x0 ?

Comment: no. It's value is 0x0 when you set it or any other function to 0x0. You can never rely on the value of  ``al`` when you have not set

Comment: @dl11: You know that AL is the low byte of EAX, right?  Did an earlier instruction do something like `movzx eax, byte [mem]` to efficiently load a byte, without partial-register-write problems?  Because movzx load / byte store is how GCC normally copies a byte.

Comment: @PeterCordes good Comment. Forgot that to mention

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I had this instruction right before!  I had forgot this detail :) thank you both for your help